# Benchmarking the UX on five different airlines

Tags: usability, interaction-design, usability-testing

This might be a bit academic, which actually true. But, the question is how to benchmark and compare five different airlines websites? which criteria should I use?

Right now, am counting how many clicks would it take to complete purchasing a ticket, I'm also looking for number of languages and currencies they offer. Am I on the right track? whether yes or no, how should I continue?

Best

Comment: What is the goal of the comparison?

Comment: to evaluate and rank (usability benchmark) thier consumer interfaces.

Comment: If you're trying to evaluate usability, then you need to focus on the overall experience...not specific (and somewhat arbitrary) criteria like click-count.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're testing for usability, you're on the wrong track altogether.  Counting clicks is a terrible measure of ease-of-use; "number of languages and currencies" is a feature comparison, not a usability comparison.

Usability benchmarking is a big subject, but in general you want to identify one or more core tasks that can be performed on all the sites you're comparing, and for each, measure things like the average amount of time it takes a new user to complete the task (including what percentage of them fail to complete it at all), or the number of errors or wrong turns that are encountered in the process (though this last can be somewhat subjective, as it's not always clear what constitutes an error).

A single tester going through all five sites in sequence will not give meaningful results, as knowledge gained while working with the first site will affect the results on later ones; you really need a large enough set of testers for each site to account for variations in individual users' skill and knowledge, with each tester assigned to a random one of the sites you're comparing.

Answer (score 6):

Usability is not the same as UX. From your comment, you need to conduct usability benchmark. To make benchmark, you need to:

1. Define some metrics
2. Get the metrics
3. Compare the metrics

Sounds simply, right?
.

### 1. Usability Testing

[According to ISO standard](https://www.w3.org/2002/Talks/0104-usabilityprocess/slide3-0.html), usability has three metrics:

- Effectiveness -- the number of errors
- Efficiency -- time for the task completion
- Satisfaction -- users' comfort and acceptance (use [SUS](https://www.usability.gov/how-to-and-tools/methods/system-usability-scale.html) to measure it).

The best way to benchmark is to conduct usability testing with 3-5 participants and to measure and compare these metrics. You need to develop several typical scenarios and test these with users.

The results should be presented in a comparison table.

**Reference:**

1. **Procedure:** the description and results are in the [Usability Metrics](https://www.nngroup.com/articles/usability-metrics/) by J. Nielsen
2. **Documentation:** all documents/templates you need for usability testing are on the [Usability.gov](https://www.usability.gov/)
   .

### 2. Heuristic evaluation

Another way to benchmark usability are Heuristic evaluation, or Cognitive Walkthrough. The metric is the number of issues you'll find and their severity ratings.

**Reference:**

1. [How to Conduct a Heuristic Evaluation](https://www.nngroup.com/articles/how-to-conduct-a-heuristic-evaluation/)
2. [How to Conduct a Cognitive Walkthrough](https://www.interaction-design.org/literature/article/how-to-conduct-a-cognitive-walkthrough)
   .

Comment: What you are saying makes alot of sense, our supervisor talked about metrics but didnt difine them!

Comment: @MajaHansson yes, the metrics translate an abstract task to the very simple task of comparing numbers )

Answer (score 1):

Benchmarking of the websites are totally connected to the service of these five companies. For instance x company can handle cancelation in a different way than y company. Additionally, finding a ticket(with exact date) at z company may be totally different than k company. Lost luggage application can be another differentiation point.

For a good comparison, you have to benchmark first their services. After understanding the main differences as service, you can also compare the same common tasks and how they are designed.

X company's purchasing flow can be best. Company Z is very successful how to handle complaints. According to who? Users...

So what can you do?

1- Draw service map of these five companies and features at their website.Create hypothesis and test your hypothesis.

2- Compare them with users.

Try to make hypothesis about your decision. Why do you think that language number is important for usability? For example, an airline that has lines to 150 countries can have 150 language while an airline to 40 countries can have 34 languages? Number of languages may be not that important...